# How to downgrade from Processing 2.6 to 2.2?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have QGIS 2.8.2 installed and Processing Toolbox 2.6.

I want to test a thing and I need to install processing Toolbox 2.2 in QGIS 2.8.2. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download 2.2 from http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing/version/2.2.0-2/ and then replace the processing folder in your user directory ~/.qgis/python/plugins with the content of the 2.2 zip file. I'm not sure if Processing 2.2 is compatible with QGIS 2.8 though.